# PSCommand Not Working on Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-runtime, exchange-server, office365

I am building an windows store app . I need to connect to exchange server through powershell commands. So to execute my commands i wrote the following code.

```
PSCommand d_cmd = new PSCommand();
            d_cmd.AddCommand("$secure_string_pwd = convertto-securestring 'testpa' -asplaintext -force");
            d_cmd.AddCommand("$username = 'test@email.com'");
            d_cmd.AddCommand("$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $secure_string_pwd");
            d_cmd.AddCommand("Import-Module MSOnline");
            d_cmd.AddCommand("$O365Cred = Get-Credential");
            d_cmd.AddCommand("$O365Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $O365Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection");
            d_cmd.AddCommand("Import-PSSession $O365Session");
```

When i am executing the above i am getting following error as follows..

Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll.

When i removed the system.management.automation that error is gone but not executed powershell commands.

Can anybody suggest me on how we can execute powershell commands in windows store apps?

Comment: Are you running this interactively? Because Get-Credential with no arguments opens up a dialog box asking for credentials. Also, you are not using `$cred`.

Comment: Looks like you should be using `$cred` instead of `$O365Cred` in the line that begins with `"$O365Session = New-PSSession `.

Comment: If i commented that Get-Credential as well it is giving same error. I think it is problem with the system.management.automation DLL. Any alternatives for this?

When i commented out all the statements above as well it is giving an error like "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll."

Comment: When i removed the reference DLL system.management.automation then there is no errors. Any Solutions to workout this?

Comment: Are you saying that when you remove the reference DLL system.management.automation, it works? Also, when you say that when you commented out all the statements, you mean all except the first?

Comment: I mean all the statements i mentioned above are commented out then also i am getting error like "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll."

When i removed that system.management.automation DLL that mscorlib.dll error gone away but unable to run powershell commands why because that DLL required for powershell. Is there any other DLLs that supports powershell commands?

Comment: I don't know if there are alternatives but for the error you are getting, perhaps this will help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c2fe60a-9299-4740-a568-3f1e3e0c828e/cannot-find-type-systemsystemexception-in-module-mscorlibdll?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Search provides other hits directly on this error, take a look at those also.